# macos Big Sur matplotlib chart displaying extra data, while Windows, Linux Mint working properly

Tags: python, matplotlib, macos-big-sur

**Pls help, I'm desperate and behind schedule** , I've tried to solve this over 1 week for a solution but nothing!
I have been working on a relatively simple cross platform python app. This app works correctly in Windows 10/11 and Linux Mint **but not in MacOS, Big Sur.**
The app uses matplotlib + tkinter to display an animated chart, updated  every 1 second, with live data yanked from the OS (wireless signal strength)

I have used the following commands code to *suppress any X-axis labeling*-

```
ax.tick_params(reset=True)
ax.tick_params('y', left=False, right=False, bottom=False, labelsize=8)
ax.tick_params('x', labelbottom=False, bottom=False, top=False)
```

This code properly ensures no data is displayed on x-axis (as expected) on Windows 10, 11, Linux Mint, BUT on MacOS Big Sur (11.7) it displays the latest/newest x-axis, x value on the extreme rhs of the chart, basically only labeling the newest data value of the x-axis. See image below, the number in the red dashed rectangle shouldn't display.

[image: macos displaying plot incorrectly]

**Interestingly I was able to recreate the same issue for all OS's** by changing the above lines to the following code:

```
ax.tick_params('x', labelbottom=False, bottom=False,reset=True)
ax.tick_params('y', left=False, right=False, bottom=False, labelsize=8)
```

**PS** I did see the issue with macos backends and using the framework version, **my understanding is that I am using the Macos "framework version": pythonw on the macos installed thru anaconda**

Comment: Why did i get negative ratings on the question?

Answer (score 1):

It looks a lot like an offset rather than the newest value to me.
Have you tried to

```py
ax.xaxis.get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
```

Just to see if it changes something (or even solve the problem)?

Another thing you could try, in case it is really a label, not an offset, is to specify a formatter

```py
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.NullFormatter())
```

or

```py
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter("tick"))
```

This last one, is a test to check if this is really ticks.
If you only see "tick", you can try to solve the problem (bypass it, rather) by

```py
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter(" "))
```

(Tho, if this works, then NullFormatter should have work either. But, hard to say what works in a situation where none of that should have been necessary anyway)

Comment: Thanks, It changed the number to 1e9. Do keep in mind that the x axis values are timestamps values like: 1666217266.1329641 

PS I'll start reading up on what an offset is in the meantime

Comment: @CustosMortem I added some other bypassing you could try

Comment: Note that it would help to have a minimal reproducible example. I can't reproduce this behavious on my macos big sur. Maybe it is because of something in the rest of your code. Maybe it if because of some configuration difference. Hard to say without a reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you so much! the follwoing fixed it-

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.NullFormatter())

on the other hand I'm going to go ahead and reduce the x-axis value size, as well since that huge number is causing the issue.

Comment: PS it seems to have introduced another minor issue: when the max y axis size of the plot changes dynamically due to fluctuations in y value of the data it doesn't reset back properly like it used to. Not a huge issue I will try to fix it myself for now.